# array modifier not working properly

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]
hi,I'm trying to make a floor tiles and the array modifier is not aligning exactly...

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Although it is difficult to know exactly how this happened,  I can reproduce your result if I rotated the mesh  while in edit mode.  Then every tile will be skewed in the array.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hello, I uploaded my file..  @moonboots

Comment: @user137101 you need to share the link (URL) your upload generates